# Adding new active directory with new domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a few question since very quite new on Active Directory and got confused between AD migration and AD replication. I have a small Active Directory project on customer production site. There have 2 existing AD server use Windows Server 2008R2 a 2003 where 2008r2 becomes primary and 2003 as secondary. Both AD server run as active-active redundant configuration. Existing server have DNS and NTPServer enabled. The customer decided to change OS to server 2012 R2 and root domain names( eg :from abc.local to xyz.local).

The question are :

1. How do I export all AD user info and Group Policy from existing AD Server to new server 2012R2. Do I need to followed the migration process by using  step adprep and forestprep.
2. Is it possible not to decommission the existing AD server right now?since I believe rolled back planned can be initiated if something happen.

3.pre-caution for AD migration? what I should test after the migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I don't sound rude, but your customer should hire someone who knows how to maintain Active Directory.

The fact you say things like "primary" and "secondary" DCs shows a really concerning level of ignorance. There is no such thing as "primary" and "secondary" domain controllers in AD. It is a multi-master environment (not "active-active"). There are FSMO roles that are hosted on a DC, but they do not affect replication or group policy propagation (well, one role does, but not for this purpose).

I'm going to explain some very high-level factors and basic instructions so that you can somewhat understand what you're in for.

You have two things here: increase the server operating version for the domain controllers, and do a domain rename.

Let's start with the easy part, the server and domain upgrade.

1. Is the domain healthy? If not, don't even start. Do you/the client have a Premier Support account with Microsoft? If not, **do NOT proceed**. Make it a condition.
2. To upgrade the domain controllers, you should be going to Server 2016, minimum. 2012 R2 is now out of mainstream support. Do not bother with it now. For domain features, it doesn't make too much difference, but it helps with newer features like Windows Hello. The best part about it is that it is *under **mainstream support** by Microsoft*.
3. Are the clients using DHCP to get their network addresses? How do servers get their DNS settings? DHCP, or GPO? If not, and domain servers or other clients have hard-coded DNS client settings, you will probably need to "recycle" the existing DC IPs to ensure you don't lose DNS on your client machines.
4. Do you have any legacy workstations in the domain? Anything less than Windows 7/Server 2008 R2? If you do, then you are already going to run into problems. Yes, you can upgrade the domain, but you will need to figure out some security policies. Ideally, all legacy member machines should be removed from the domain first. It's really bad there's still a 2003 DC.
5. Is anything relying on anonymous LDAP binds to do LDAP queries on the DCs? If so, fix them. Unless it's more than 25 years old, an LDAP client should be able to authenticate to do LDAP queries. Do not proceed until any such app is fixed (create a service account for it to use to do LDAP - it doesn't need any special privileges for normal queries).
6. Are any accounts configured to use DES-only encryption? I don't care what the 20-year-old SAP Note says, it's wrong (unless your SAP is 20 years old). Fix any accounts using DES-only encryption. There are scripts to find them. Google.
7. Ascertain the forest and domain functional level. It must be at least 2003 Native mode. If not, you won't be able to proceed with adding a 2016 DC (which, again, you should. No arguments.) I am assuming there is only one AD site. **Check** this is the case.
8. In DNS, are all the zones AD-integrated? If there are any primary zones that are on the DCs that are **not** AD-integrated, then go ahead and convert them. Replication should be to "All DNS servers in this domain/forest" (either is fine, domain is default).
9. Is the _msdcs zone a separate zone? Or is it "underneath" the main domain zone? If it's not a separate zone, move it out. There's a whole procedure for that.
10. Are there any secondary zones replicated by the DCs? If so, they should be documented - secondary zone configs are per-DNS server. They are not stored in the AD database. Similarly, any primary zones that are replicating out to external secondary servers should have those configs documented - again, they are per-DNS server settings, not domain-wide.
11. Document the **DNS forwarders** for each DC. This is critical. There are scripts that will dump out DNS configs - run them for each DC because they may have different configurations.
12. Document the NTP (time service) configuration for the PDCE emulator FSMO role-holder. I highly recommend that NTP be configured via group policy. There are guides if you google.
13. Build an off-line lab environment (you need at least two machines that can communicate over the network for BASIC tests), backup the Active Directory and restore it to one computer to your lab, making it the new DC. Then promote the other lab server as another DC. Check replication works. Check to see if you can add a client machine to the domain in your lab and authenticate, add new users, etc. If you do not know how to restore Active Directory and rebuild a domain, you should **stop** right now.
14. When you've tested your AD restore process, you can plan your upgrade. You should know if there are extreme legacy clients (pre-2008 R2/Windows 7) and ideally have plans to get rid of them before the upgrade. If the client doesn't want to make plans to retire legacy machines, walk away from the job (since you obviously don't have enough experience to deal with the complications of difficult clients).
15. Now for the upgrade. If you don't **understand** any of the following steps, **stop** now and do not proceed.
16. This assumes you need to recycle your DC IP addresses to keep the DNS clients working. If you can change your DNS for **all** domain clients (including servers) via GPO or DHCP scope configurations, then it's not so important. I think you should retain at least one of the existing IP addresses "just in case" (unless you have to build on a new network).
17. I recommend doing any DCPromo or DC reboots over the weekend or after hours. The base server builds for the new DCs can happen any time. Get the AD Replication Status Tool from Microsoft (free download) and install it somewhere - can be any member server/jump box.
18. Build the first 2016 server that will become the new DC and join it to the domain. Use any IP for now - DHCP is fine. Install the DNS, AD DS, DFS Namespaces and DFS Replication roles and features. And probably WINS. Consider completely removing all other roles and features that aren't installed yet. Especially remove SMB1 (since you're not servicing any legacy clients, *are you*?)
19. Do AD forestprep and domain prep with the 2016 server. Domain\forestprep will run by itself when you do DCpromo, but it's best to do it separately and ensure the domain replicates the new schema and is in good health. This can be done any time.
20. If the domain/forestprep works fine, wait overnight and check replication/ad health in the morning.
21. Transfer the FSMO roles to the 2008 R2 server (if they're not already there)
22. Allocate a new temporary IP address for the 2003 domain controller. Ensure you note the "old" address (for recycling on the new DC).
23. On the 2003 DC, change the DNS client configuration on the network adapter so that the 2008 R2 DC is first, its old IP is second, the new IP is third and 127.0.0.1 is last.
24. Change the IP address to the temporary one on the 2003 DC. Reboot it and ensure the Netlogon service registers the SRV records for the new IP in the _msdcs namespace in DNS. Note that your DNS clients will now only resolve one server for DNS queries. (This is why this should be done after hours/weekend)
25. Check `DCDIAG`, domain replication, authentication on the 2003 DC. See if there are any SRV records in _msdcs still pointing to the 2003 DC's old IP address. If there are any in there, delete them. Try not to delete the new IPs! But if you make a mistake, just restart `NETLOGON` on the DC and it will reregister the records. Run the AD Replication Status Tool and check all well. If all is working, you can add the first 2016 DC.
26. On the new 2016 server, ensure the network client DNS is configured to point to the 2008 R2 DC for its DNS. Change the server IP address to a static entry, using the old 2003 IP address. Reboot the server. Then you can DCpromo the 2016 domain controller. It should be a Global Catalog. After about half an hour to ensure it's all working, check the SYSVOL is shared on the server, replication is working if you do `repadmin /replsum`, no errors in `DCDIAG`, no serious errors in event log, and accounts are authenticating to the new DC. If `DCDIAG` shows some errors, check again in an hour.
27. On the new 2016 DC, once healthy, update the server network configuration so that its DNS settings has the 2008 R2 DC first, its own IP address next, and 127.0.0.1 last.
28. Update the DNS forwarders in the DNS server console. Ensure you recreate the configuration of any secondary zones, secondary masters and any other detail you extracted from the 2003 server DNS service config.
29. Wait a few days/over the weekend and check all is in good health in the domain. Run AD Replication Status Tool. Do another AD backup (you should be doing these daily anyway - make sure you're not overwriting the same backup during the DC upgrades!).
30. **VERY IMPORTANT** - ensure the new 2016 DC is getting DNS requests from the domain clients and is servicing them.
31. Wait a day/overnight and check all is in good health in the domain.
32. Build your next 2016 DC, install the same roles as the first, and join it to the domain. Configure the network adapter DNS to point to the other 2016 DC for DNS first, its own IP next and 127.0.0.1 last.
33. Allocate a temporary IP address to the 2008 R2 DC.
34. Similar to the 2003 server, configure the 2008 R2 DNS client on the network adapter to point to the 2016 server first, its old IP second, the tempory IP third and 127.0.0.1 last. Assign the new IP address to the network adapter and reboot. Ensure Netlogon registers the SRV records for itself in the _msdcs zone.
35. Do all the checks on the 2008 R2 server and ensure SYSVOL is shared, replication is working if you do `repadmin /replsum`, no errors in DCDIAG, no serious errors in event log, and accounts are authenticating. Wait overnight to ensure that all is working fine and recheck in the morning.
36. See if there are any SRV records in the _msdcs zone still pointing to the 2003 DC's old IP address. If there are any in there, delete them.
37. On the new 2016 server, ensure the network client DNS is configured to point to the 2016 DC for its DNS. Change the server IP address to the old Server 2008 R2 address. Reboot the server.
38. Then DCpromo the 2016 domain controller - global catalog again. After about half an hour to ensure it's all working, check the SYSVOL is shared on the server, replication is working if you do `repadmin /replsum`, no errors in `DCDIAG`, no serious errors in event log, and accounts are authenticating to the new DC. If `DCDIAG` shows some errors, check again in an hour.
39. On the new 2016 DC, update the DNS forwarders in the DNS server console. Ensure you recreate the configuration of any secondary zones, secondary masters and any other detail you extracted from the 2008 R2 server DNS service config.
40. Once the new DC is healthy, the next day, update the network adapter on the FIRST 2016 DC to have the NEW 2016 DC as the first DNS server in the list, its own IP as the next DNS, and finally 127.0.0.1. Run the AD Replication Status Tool for good measure.
41. Now you have 4 DCs - two legacy ones and two new 2016 servers. The new servers are using the legacy DCs former IP addresses, so DNS should be fine for clients.
42. Transfer your FSMO roles to one of the 2016 DCs. Ensure `DCDIAG` and `repadmin` show replication working OK. If you haven't bothered with configuring the PDCE NTP service via GPO, fix it now on the new PDCE (just do the GPO).
43. Wait a few days - to the next weekend. Do backups! AD Replication Status Tool. If the domain is healthy, demote the 2003 DC and remove it from the domain. Perform metadata clean-up if necessary. Make sure the 2003 DC is deleted from AD Sites and Services wherever it occurs, and all the 2003 DC SRV records are removed from the _msdcs DNS zone.
44. Wait a few more days - the next weekend! Backups. Domain health. AD Replication Status Tool. If all is good, demote the 2008 R2 DC and remove it from the domain. Perform metadata clean-up if necessary. Make sure the 2008 R2 DC is deleted from AD Sites and Services wherever it occurs, and all the 2008 R2 DC SRV records are removed from the _msdcs DNS zone.
45. Now you have two 2016 DCs running a 2003 native-mode forest and domain. You're not done yet. Do your domain health checks. AD Replication Status Tool.
46. Schedule the domain and forest functional level upgrade, and SYSVOL migration to DFSR. Do not allow clients to put the DFL/FFL upgrade off. It's pointless and leaves the domain without many of the benefits of new AD functions. Here is the guide to FFL and DFLs. The most important changes in terms of security happened in 2008/2012, where AES encryption types for kerberos became available, and the DES encryption types were deprecated. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels. Migrating the SYSVOL to DFSR has no impact - it's just a bit fiddly.
47. BACKUPS
48. You need to migrate your FRS SYSVOL to DFSR. I did your googling for you and this is the *authoritative* guide. Follow it. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/filecab/2014/06/25/streamlined-migration-of-frs-to-dfsr-sysvol/
49. Once the SYSVOL is done and replicating with no errors, proceed with the DFL/FFL. I hope you've read all the doco about potential security aspects. If you paid attention to the caveats I put at the start (no DES-only accounts, no anonymous LDAP, etc), then it shouldn't be a big deal. Read the guide above. Follow the links. Then proceed to follow the steps linked at the end of the document to do the DFL first, then the FFL. Check the AD health! The good thing about these steps is that if it goes pear-shaped, it's pretty obvious quickly. **Call Microsoft** if it does. Do not mess around.

Now, while these steps look highly detailed, they are NOT. I haven't discussed WINS, which is the curse of Satan. I haven't even bothered asking about the size of this AD. I'm hoping for your sake it's less than a few thousand users in a single site. With 2 DCs, you couldn't possibly be servicing any more. I haven't talked about those impacts for Kerberos encryption and what non-domain-joined crap in the environment might be using AD that you don't know about.

In my last job, we found out that the software uses to manage the entire network was using an insecure LDAP configuration pointing to a single legacy DC IP (not even a DNS name) which we only discovered because we decided we didn't need to recycle that address, and turned off that particular DC (which was the *second* one with that address - they should have fixed their config before then). Let me tell you, network engineers get very agitated when they can't maintain critical infrastructure in a public-safety organisation, even when they were told months in advance to fix any systems using these protocols. (And years previously when the old-old DCs were decommissioned! This why I prefer not to recycle IPs for DCs that aren't doing primary/secondary DNS - it weeds out the misconfigured system).

What's their change control and documentation process? How will you do proper testing?

Testing the AD backup and domain recovery is the bare minimum to even start. It is **not testing** to see that your applications will work with new AD security, some of which is introduced when you install a new DC with a higher operating system - Server 2012 R2 is a big change. This is nothing to do with the DFL/FFL, by the way. It's the DC operating system.

And we haven't even gone into new domain security configurations and updating GPOs to reflect current best-practice (if they have a 2003 DC, they likely don't care that much, unless this is an attempt to fix things up... with an inexperienced tech). Like getting rid of NTLMv1, SMB1, etc etc.

How happy is the business with not having access to **anything** for possibly days if you mess this up? Assuming you have Premier Support help, of course.

I've written all this quasi-detail to hopefully scare you so much you'll recommed they'll engage someone with the appropriate experience.

Answer (score 1):

For the domain rename, WHY?

If you're using any of the following products in the domain (and probably the 2016 versions as well), you **can't**.

Microsoft Exchange 2000 Server
Microsoft Exchange Server 2007
Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
Microsoft Exchange Server 2013
Microsoft Internet Security and Acceleration (ISA) Server 2004
Microsoft Live Communications Server 2005
Microsoft Operations Manager 2005
Microsoft SharePoint Portal Server 2003
Microsoft Systems Management Server (SMS) 2003
Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007
Microsoft Office Communications Server 2007 R2
Microsoft System Center Operations Manager 2007 SP1
Microsoft System Center Operations Manager 2007 R2
Microsoft Lync Server 2010
Microsoft Lync Server 2013

Link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/300684/deployment-and-operation-of-active-directory-domains-that-are-configur).

If you don't have any SCOM, SCCM, Exchange, Lync or Skype, or you're using the O365 versions (first time I've thought of an actual benefit for O365 in an enterprise) then the procedure to do it is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc738208(v=ws.10)). Good luck.

The only other option is to do the migration to a new forest. If you're using on-prem Exchange, SCCM, Skype, yadda yadda, good luck integrating those after migrating your users, computers, applications etc etc that depend on your current AD.

I've never touched a forest migration and I've been doing this for over 20 years.